# Shortening a list

Tags: python, list

I have a simple question that I can't seem to find the answer to. I have a `list` in `python` that I want to make shorter based on the values at the end. For example say I have `list = [0,0,1,2,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,0]` I want to remove any 0's that are at the end or beginning of the list so this translates into `list = [1,2,1,2,2,2,0,1,1]`. I tried using `filter()` but this is removing all instances of 0 when I just want to remove the ends. I'm new to python and can't seem to figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Don't call a list `list` It will override the list constructor >:-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while list[0] == 0:
   list.pop(0)
while list[-1] == 0:
   list.pop()
```

but it's best not to use a variable named `list` because that overrides the built-in `list` type.

Comment: The first loop could be quite slow though (if there are several zeros at the beginning). If necessary, it could be optimized: Count the leading zeros, then `del list[:clz]`

Comment: @delnan or `l = list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x == 0, l))`.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def list_strip(sequence, item):
    leading = sum(1 for el in takewhile(lambda L: L == item, sequence))
    trailing = sum(1 for el in takewhile(lambda L: L == item, reversed(sequence)))
    slc = slice(leading, -trailing or None)
    return sequence[slc]
```

Comment: If I were a betting man, I'd bet on this being the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit: I like this approach better:

```
def trim(lst, key=lambda i:i==0):
  g = [(k,list(group)) for k, group in groupby(lst, key=key)]
  if g[0][0]: del g[0]
  if g[-1][0]: del g[-1]
  return list(chain.from_iterable(group[1] for group in g))
```

#### Original:

The left trim can be handled very handily with itertools, but itertools isn't quite as good with the ends of lists.

```
def ltrim(lst, v=0):
  return list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda i:i==v, lst))

def rtrim(lst, v=0):
  return reversed(ltrim(reversed(lst), v))

def trim(lst, v=0):
  return ltrim(rtrim(lst, v), v)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `pop` method:
`L.pop([index]) -> item` -- remove and return item at index (default last).
 Raises IndexError if list is empty or index is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [88]: L = [0,0,1,2,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,10,0]

In [89]: s = ','.join(str(i) for i in L)

In [90]: while s[-2:] == ',0':
   ....:     s = s[:-2]
   ....:     

In [91]: while s[:2] == '0,':
   ....:     s = s[2:]
   ....:     

In [92]: [int(i) for i in s.split(',')]
Out[92]: [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 10]
```

Better yet:

```
In [102]: L = [0,0,1,2,1,2,2,2,0,1,1,10,0]

In [103]: blacklist = set()

In [104]: mid = False

In [105]: for i,num in enumerate(L):      
    if not mid and not num:
        blacklist.add(i)
    elif num:
        mid = True

In [106]: mid = False

In [107]: for i,num in enumerate(reversed(L)):
    if not mid and not num:
        blacklist.add(len(L)-i)
    elif num:
        mid = True

In [108]: [num for i,num in enumerate(L) if i not in blacklist]
Out[108]: [1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 10]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with double-digit numbers, though.

Comment: Better. :-)  I don't think you need the `.strip(',')`, though, since `strip` treats its argument as a set of characters.

Comment: @DSM: good catch. Can't handle that with a one-liner anymore. Check out the update

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Although without the convenience of a one-liner, I think converting to strings and back is probably not a good use of computation.

Comment: @SamMussmann: I agree. I did notice that and posted an update, just as you posted your comment

Comment: @inspectorG4dget You probably want `reversed(L)` rather than `L[::-1]` to avoid making a copy.  Also, rather than setting `mid = True`, you could just `break` out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

May not be most efficient, but one way is

```
>>> myList
[0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> [int(str_element) for str_element in "".join(str(int_element) for int_element in myList).strip('0')]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: This doesn't work with multiple digit numbers, though. E.g. `[1002]`.

Comment: My bad, sorry. Should I delete my answer since @inspectorG4dget seems to be on the same line of thought?